# The scale down doesn't work azure

Tags: azure, asp.net-web-api, scale, webjob

I build a webjob that fetch messages from services bus, after that, this service sends the messages to webapi.

The webapi is hosted on App Serivice plan.This plan is setting with Premium P3 and 10 instance, where there are copies of webapi.

When webjob runs it sends to webapi 200 messages each request, each iteration of webjob sends 5 messages following to same endpoint and the same webapi. The requests are async, so the webjob does not wait request to finish.

Analyzing the Application Insight is possible to see that two requests are received and two servers are working. Other three requests stay on stand by until one instance finishes its requests. After one server finishes, another server starts its work on request.

I supposed that all server receives all requests and works at same time, because all App Service there are load balance by default. Why do all servers don't work together?

I turned off the affinity of server, all servers are stateless.

I guess the reason is because the request are made by one client, but even then I'm not sure what happened.

Sorry by my English

Comment: Would you mind sharing the info about how long  the instances  deal with the request?

Comment: Tom Sun, I was sending 5 request and had 10 instance, but just 2 instances were work.

Comment: This issue I solved setting autoscale. With autoscale others servers began to work. Then I suppose that load balance didn't send requests to another server because  the servers didn't use all resources.